# How do I simplify the sum of sine and cosine in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry, symbolic-math

How do I simplify `a*sin(wt) + b*cos(wt)` into `c*sin(wt+theta)` using SymPy? For example:

f = sin(t) + 2*cos(t) = 2.236*sin(t + 1.107)

I tried the following:

```
from sympy import *
t = symbols('t')
f=sin(t)+2*cos(t)
trigsimp(f)     #Returns sin(t)+2*cos(t)
simplify(f)     #Returns sin(t)+2*cos(t)
f.rewrite(sin)  #Returns sin(t)+2*sin(t+Pi/2)
```

PS.: I dont have direct access to `a,b and w`. Only to `f`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer can be achieved by noting that you want to have

`a * sin(t) + b * cos(t) = A * (cos(c)*sin(t) + sin(c)*cos(t))`

This leads to a simultaneous equation `a = A * cos(c)` and `b = A * sin(c)`.

Dividing the second equation by the second, we can solve for `c`. Substituting its solution into the first equation, you can solve for `A`.

I followed the same pattern but just to get it in terms of cos. If you want to get it in terms of sin, you can use Rodrigo's formula.

The following code should be able to take any linear combination of the form x * sin(t - w) or y * cos(t - z). There can be multiple sins and cos'.

```py
from sympy import *

t = symbols('t', real=True)
expr = sin(t)+2*cos(t)  # unknown

d = collect(expr.expand(trig=True), [sin(t), cos(t)], evaluate=False)
a = d[sin(t)]
b = d[cos(t)]

cos_phase = atan(a/b)
amplitude = a / sin(cos_phase)
print(amplitude.evalf() * cos(t - cos_phase.evalf()))
```

Which gives

```
2.23606797749979*cos(t - 0.463647609000806)
```

This seems to be a satisfactory match after plotting both graphs.

You could even have something like

```py
expr = 2*sin(t - 3) + cos(t) - 3*cos(t - 2)
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
a * sin(wt) + b * cos(wt) = sqrt(a**2 + b**2) * sin(wt + acos(a / sqrt(a**2 + b**2)))
```

While the **amplitude** is the radical `sqrt(a**2 + b**2)`, the **phase** is given by the arccosine of the ratio `a / sqrt(a**2 + b**2)`, which may not be expressible in terms of arithmetic operations and radicals. Hence, you may be asking SymPy to do the impossible. Better use **floating-point** values, but you do not need SymPy for that.

Comment: I know that this simplification is not always valid. How can i make sympy simplify it when it is possible?

Comment: The set of cases where it is possible is very small, isn't it? For nonnegative `a`, you can compare `a / sqrt(a**2 + b**2)` to `1`, `sqrt(3)/2`, `sqrt(2)/2`, `1/2`, `0`.

Comment: I know how to simplify it by hand when it is possible. I would like to know if there were an elegant method with sympy. If there isnt, I need to extract the coefficients w, a and b and I can make my own routine

Comment: This simplification is common on “Engineering Process Control”

Comment: Also common in electrical engineering. If you're happy enough with `acos(a / sqrt(a**2 + b**2))`, then there is no problem. Forget about finding the exact value of the phase, just care about finding exact values for the sine and cosine of the phase.

Comment: Your answer has a mathematical point of view. I still need ta function that recieves an expression of sin and cos and returns only sin

Comment: That function is trivial: `return (sqrt(a**2 + b**2), acos(a / sqrt(a**2 + b**2)))`.

Comment: I dont have a and b, i need to extract them

Comment: `a` and `b` can be extracted by visual inspection of `print f`.